# Can I escape a shortcode from a Hugo theme from blogdown

Tags: r-markdown, hugo, blogdown, hugo-shortcode

I'm using a hugo theme: https://github.com/shawnohare/hugo-tufte which allows for the use of the shortcode `{{% marginnote %}}...{{% /marginnote %}}` to create a margin note.

I want to output the actual text `{{% marginnote %}}...{{% /marginnote %}}` on my final page, but all my attempts to escape the shortcode have come up short.

Wrapping it with `'`s as you would in Hugo is not successful.
Neither is escaping those quotes
Nor wrapping it in a code block.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To escape Hugo shortcode calls, use syntax like this:

```
{{%/* marginnote */%}}
...
{{%/* /marginnote */%}}
```

I wrote about this in [Escaping Hugo shortcodes](https://www.ii.com/hugo-tips-fragments/#_11_escaping_hugo_shortcodes) in my *Hugo Tips and Fragments* article.

I learned about this in [discourse.gohugo.io](https://discourse.gohugo.io/) in the thread [How is the Hugo Doc site showing shortcodes in code blocks?](https://discourse.gohugo.io/t/how-is-the-hugo-doc-site-showing-shortcodes-in-code-blocks/9074).

Comment: Thanks! Of course now that I know the syntax it seems to pop up everywhere, but I swear that I searched high and low for this and couldn't find it anywhere.

Comment: One of the reasons I wrote about this on my website is that it's not easy (for me) to remember this syntax or to find it documented. I'm realizing that my site is basically a personal wiki of all the things I think I'll have a hard time remembering. I'm happy it helped!